# emacs - exclude json-mode from js-mode-hook

Tags: javascript, json, emacs

I am developing Javascript using Emacs.

I have a function that formats my Javascript code into [Standard Style](http://standardjs.com/) on file save. My configuration looks like this:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'standardfmt t t)))
```

Unfortunately this hook has the side effect of applying to buffers using `json-mode` as well, since `json-mode` extends from `js-mode`.

Is there an easy way to exclude`json-mode` buffers from this hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (unless (derived-mode-p 'json-mode)
      (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'standardfmt t t))))
```

or alternatively

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (when (eq major-mode 'js-mode) ;; Not a derived mode.
      (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'standardfmt t t))))
```